# NativeScript How can I redirect camera stream to HTML Canvas?

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I know there are native scripts modules for camera capture and barcode scanning.

I'm looking for something different:
I need to redirect camera input to an HTML canvas (live).

Google Chrome supports this feature but Apple products don't

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no developed NativeScript plugin for streaming from Android camera, However, you can develop your own plugin using an Android library like [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming)

> libstreaming is an API that allows you, with only a few lines of code,
>   to stream the camera and/or microphone of an android powered device
>   using RTP over UDP.
>
> Android 4.0 or more recent is required. Supported encoders include
>   H.264, H.263, AAC and AMR.

Nice API reference is available [here](http://majorkernelpanic.com/libstreaming/doc-v4/)

More about how to develop your plugin in NativeScript ca be found [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins)
Also, you might want to have some knowledge of [marshalling (data conversion) in NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/marshalling/java-to-js.html)